# Blackberry 10 WebView: Content doesn't get updated after URL changes

Tags: c++, qt, webview, blackberry, qml

I wrote a code that updates WebView URL of Blackberry main.qml after certain process gets executed. Qt/C++ code that updates WebView URL is given below

```
QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);
qml->setContextProperty("app",this);
AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
responseWebPage = root->findChild<WebView *>("responseWebPage");
responseWebPage->setUrl(QUrl(homePath + "/Appname/updatedhtml.html"));
```

WebView section of main.qml is

```
WebView {
   id: responseWebPage
   objectName: "responseWebPage"
   accessibility.name: "responseWebPage"
   url: "local:///assets/initialcontent.html"                                                
   onUrlChanged: {
      console.debug("URL is changed. New URL is " + responseWebPage.url);
   }
}
```

I am able to see updated URL name in logs printed by WebView console debug. I also verified that that updatedhtml.html file exists. (Checked through Target File System Navigator). Yet after the URL is set, I do not see content of updatedhtml.html being displayed either in device or simulator. Is there any step I am missing? Any help is greatly appreciated